# how to provide starting directory for __import__ function in python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a class which could be configured by the configs. It has this file structure:

```
-BaseModel
--Model1
---config
--Model2
---config
etc
```

and inside model constructor I read exact config depending from input params with `__import__`

I want to add `BaseModel2(BaseModel)` inherited from `BaseModel`

And my file structure will change to that

```
-BaseModel
-BaseModel2
--BaseModel2A
---config
--BaseModel2B
---config
```

but the problem is that when I invoke `BaseModel2` constructor it invokes `BaseModel` constructor and `__import__` function inside it trying to resolve config for BaseModel instead of `BaseModel2`

So how could I directly specify start point for `__import__` function to  allow it to search in BaseModel2 subdirs instead of baseModel's ?

---

Code is very simple
BaseModel.py:

```
class BaseModel(object):
def __init__():
   ...
   config = __import__(configname, locals(), globals(), [], -1)
```

BaseModel2.py:

```
class BaseModel2(BaseModel):
def __init__():
   super(BaseModel2, self).__init__();
```

The problem is that `__import__` method invoked inside `super()` context resolving files under `BaseModel` directory, but I need to make it resolve it under `BaseModel2`

Comment: Can you show the code for what you're doing now with `__import__` to get your configuration? I don't understand it at all from your current description, which makes trying to solve your further issue impossible.

Comment: I update the question with actual code.